# log4j2 Socket Appender with SSL enabled

Tags: log4j2

Here is my log4j2 SocketAppender configured with SSL

```
<Configuration status="warn">
<Socket name="transSocketAppender" host="lxddv002.test.intranet"
port="9400" protocol="TCP" reconnectionDelayMillis="30000"
immediateFail="false">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n" charset="UTF-8" />
    <SSL>
        <Truststore location="C:\Users\AC26252\Desktop\certs\keystore.jks"
            password="123456" />
    </SSL>
</Socket>

<Async name="transSocketAsyncAppender" bufferSize="204800">
    <AppenderRef ref="transSocketAppender" />
</Async>
```

I get this error on my server restart and the first few(2 or 3) request logs are lost and not being transported.

```
2018-11-22 19:04:05,243 AsyncAppender-socketAsyncAppender ERROR Unable to write to stream TLS:lxddv002.test.intranet:9400 for appender socketAppender: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TLS:lxddv002.test.intranet:9400
2018-11-22 19:04:05,259 AsyncAppender-socketAsyncAppender ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender socketAppender
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TLS:lxddv002.test.intranet:9400
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:229)`at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:201)`
```

Is there anything wrong with my configuration? Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: You mentioned **first few** are lost, may I ask if it does log after a while like say 1-2 mins ?

Comment: Even after 5-10 mins of server restart when I hit a request the same error appears. But it does makes a connection and log after few request hits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my log4j2 version. I have upgraded to the latest version and its working fine now.